# Can I change the behavior of back browser button in angular app?

Tags: angular

I have a image(al-image) in my angular app, when I clicked on this image, I open another component that has fullscreen image, but if I click 'back' button (when image is fullscreen), my route is changing, but I want to close my fullscreen image in this case and render al-image component

**parent.component:**

```
    <al-image
                        *ngIf="!isFirstImageWasClicked; else fullscreen1"
                        (click)="onImageClick(solutionsImages[0].id)"
                        class="main-block-image"
                        [image]="solutionsImages[0].image"
                    >
                    </al-image>
                    <ng-template #fullscreen1>
                        <al-fullscreen (imageClick)="onImageClick(solutionsImages[0].id)" [imageSrc]="imageSrc1"></al-fullscreen>
                    </ng-template>
    <al-image
                        *ngIf="!isSecondImageWasClicked; else fullscreen2"
                        (click)="onImageClick(solutionsImages[1].id)"
                        class="main-block-image"
                        [image]="solutionsImages[1].image"
                    >
                    </al-image>
                    <ng-template #fullscreen2>
                        <al-fullscreen (imageClick)="onImageClick(solutionsImages[1].id)" [imageSrc]="imageSrc2"></al-fullscreen>
                    </ng-template>

public onImageClick(id: number): void {
        if (id === 1) {
            this.isFirstImageWasClicked = !this.isFirstImageWasClicked;
        } else if (id === 2) {
            this.isSecondImageWasClicked = !this.isSecondImageWasClicked;
        } else {
            this.isThirdImageWasClicked = !this.isThirdImageWasClicked;
        }
        document.documentElement.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
    }
```

**fullscren.component**

```
<div class="fullscreen-image-wrapper">
    <img class="fullscreen-image" (click)="onFullScreenImageClick()" [src]="imageSrc">
</div>

@Input() public imageSrc: string;
    @Output() public imageClick: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() {
    }

    public onFullScreenImageClick(): void {
        this.imageClick.emit();
        document.documentElement.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
    }

.fullscreen-image-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 101;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fullscreen-image {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think about only html, here:

```
<a [href]="imageSrc">
  <img class="fullscreen-image" [src]="imageSrc">
</a>
```

Edit:
Removed target="_blank"

Comment: Unfortunately, I should open full screen image in the same tab

Comment: Try without target="_blank". Edited my response.

Comment: I tried to use your response. At first al-fullscreen component is rendering, but [href]="imageSrc" is works only when I clicked on image, and then I have a zoom in icon and can't  come back in my previous state (when image is not fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

You are not routing to a new page, so you cannot use the back button.
One solution is routing to the image using the image URL.
Another solution is showing the image in a dialog.

Comment: I thought about routing to the image using URL, but did't know how to do this. The image url should be as query parameter in URL?

Comment: Check @aepifano answer